# Find minutes remaining between two times

Tags: swift, nsdate, date-comparison

I have two times in the format `HH:MM` how would I compare the second from the first one finding how many minutes left until I reach to the first time:

**example:**

```
timeOne = 12:01
timeTwo = 11:32
output = 29 minutes
```

Any help writing this in `Swift`?

Comment: NSDateFormatter, NSCalendar, NSDateComponentsFormatter

Comment: There's a great pod DateTools that correctly handles a lot of time-based calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:) can diff dates easily (assuming `start` and `end` are `NSDate` instances

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.Minute, fromDate: start, toDate: end, options: [])

components.minute
```

If you are interested in getting just the formatted string, and not the actual value, then checkout [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateComponentsFormatter/includesTimeRemainingPhrase):

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = .Minute
formatter.unitsStyle = .SpellOut
// includesTimeRemainingPhrase gives strings like "T minutes remaining"

formatter.stringFromDate(start, toDate: end)
```

By changing the `unitsStyle`, you could get different representations, such as:

```
"54m"
"54 minutes"
"54 min"
"fifty-four minutes"
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! But i wasn't using a NSDate format but i was able to convert it and execute your code! Thanks

Comment: Im getting some problem lets say i have my first time (NSDATE format but showing as a string for u) = "12:58 AM" and "1:05 PM" i do the calender.components its returns '667' not 7? Help?

Answer (score 3):

You should operate with 2 `NSDate` instances, then you may use next API:

```
let interval = laterDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(earlierDate)
```

It returns the number of seconds, as an `NSTimeInterval` value.
Divide it by 60 will give you minutes.